# i want to get the current category term in the select box in word press

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my taxonamy code in word press

```
<?php
          $terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'listing_type', 'hide_empty' => false,]);

                if ($terms) {
                foreach ($terms as $term) { 
                     $selected = 'selected';
                echo '<option value="' .  $term->name . '" '.$selected.' >' .esc_attr($term->name) . '</option>';
                }
                } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing this manually you can just use `wp_dropdown_categories()`

Docs here — https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Thanks,
Tom